# How to show error page if more than one www is being used in url?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

Usually if you type domain name with or without www it would show you the page based on Rewrite engine rule in httpd.conf

But in my case even if you type more than one www, say www.www.domain.com it would show you the home page of domain.com which should not be the case and it should show unable to determine IP or something like that.

Is there any way to avoid or fix such issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to avoid or fix such issue?

You can try this rule as your first rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.www
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Comment: It will usually show 400 bad request. My question is how t make it work like other sites i.e. if you try to open www.www.aliencoders.com , it will show you the error page displaying "Unable to determine IP address from host name www.www.aliencoders.com"  I need something similar.

Comment: sorry had a typo that I fixed. It is the way your DNS records are setup that are allowing `www.anything.domain.com`

Comment: Not anything but more than one www. www.anything.domain.com will not work anyways. Its only happening with more than one www

Comment: Well I don't know your domain so can't test its A/CNAME records but this rule should work for you.

Comment: Hope it may help you. <br /><code>$ host jassi.fs.sjaiswal
domain.com has address 100.100.200.200
$ host www.www.domain.com
www.www.domain.com has address 100.100.200.200     <br />It should work similar to the below site though
$ host aliencoders.com
aliencoders.com has address 66.147.244.127

$ host www.www.aliencoders.com
Host www.www.aliencoders.com not found
</code>

Comment: As I said that is way your hosting co. has created DNS records for you. Did you try above rule?

Comment: Yes I tried above rule and it is showing 400 Bad Request but I wanted to show unable to determine IP address like other sites do as per the given example. Thanks Anubhava :)

Comment: sorry had a missing `-`. Try it now.

Comment: Looks good and can be ok too. But it is showing Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server. What i want is to show what it shows for www.www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: That is because DNS record itself isn't found. But you can do `RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]` also that will show 404 error

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46821/discussion-between-jassi-and-anubhava)

Comment: I am on mobile noire so can't join chat. Any problems?